# Hive check condition

Tags: hive

I have the Hive table in the below mentioned format

```
UserID SmartID Category Description
1      444     Imported "Updated 444"
1      444     Accepted "Accepted 444"
1      444     Exported "Exported 444" 
2      555     Imported "Created 555"
2      555     Accepted "Accepted 555"
3      666     Imported "Updated 666"
3      666     Accepted "Accepted 666"
3      666     Deleted "Deleted 666"
```

For every user, I need only records, where SmartID's are the same and for if the combination of categories are atleast (Accepted and Imported) and description for Imported should contain the word "Updated". In the above scenario, UserID 1 and 3 are valid users for and UserId 2 is invalid. Required output

```
UserID SmartID
1      444
3      666
```

I am trying the below pasted Hive query

```
select userid,SmartID
,collect_set(case when description like '%Updated%' then description end)b,
collect_set(subcategory)c
 as CountImported,
from (
select userid,subcategory,
  description,
SmartID
from smartmatching)
a
where 
SmartID is not null 
and category in ('Imported','Accepted')
group by userid,SmartID
HAVING COUNT(category) >= 2
```

which gives me output like this and I am struck at this point ? Can somebody help me proceed to the desired output?

```
UserID SmartID b                 c         
1      444     ["Updated 444"]   ["Imported","Accepted","Exported"]
2      555     []                ["Imported","Accepted"]
3      666     ["Updated 666"]   ["Imported","Accepted","Deleted"]
```

Comment: so for UserID = 3 and Category = Imported, if SmartID is something different from 666 i.e. 111 or anything then UserId = 3 will also become invalid?

Comment: @rajenRaiyarela - Yes! It becomes invalid. For every user and smartid grouping , valid records are only those which contain atleast ("imported","accepted") and description for imported contains the word "updated"